# Запись куки Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, cookie

Как можно получить нормальную (без лишнего текста) запись куки из Yii2.

Записываю куки так:

```
$guid = '1003';

Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new Cookie([
            'name' => 'guid',
            'value' => $guid,
            'path' => 'auth'
        ]));
```

в это время в куки записывается содержимое куки так:

```
80f3cc3963723e621d0d09b5e720c33e9091d528e6fd08d1bf55bb4b37a848cfa%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A4%3A%22guid%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A4%3A%221003%22%3B%7D
```

Как получить в содержимом просто 1003? Без шифрования и дополнительного текста.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию куки все шифруются чтобы исключить возможность редактирования их за пределами фреймворка. Можно отключить валидацию и тогда по идее куки будут сохранятся в том же формате, но это не безопасно, лучше искать другие варианты.

Но всё же для отключения в конфиге пропишите следующее:

```
'request' => [
    'enableCookieValidation' => false,
    'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
]
```

Но опять же лучше посмотрите варианты чтения куки доступной [тут](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookies) и возможно он вам подойдет.

Есть ещё один вариант, вот цитата с [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookie-validation):

> Note: Cookies that are directly read/sent via $_COOKIE and setcookie()
>   will NOT be validated.

Comment: а подскажите, где в Yii можно посмотреть алгоритм самого шифрование этих куки? я так понимаю используется cookieValidationKey, задаваемый в конфиге, но какой алгоритм шифрования используется - где взять? дело в том что куки должно получать и использовать другое приложение, причём оно написано не на Yii2

Comment: @VladimirMedinsky вот тут код: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/9d9b63c05a9f641cdd99f3321c7378e0d5b62f5a/framework/web/Response.php#L363-L382

Comment: я сделал в конфиге то что Вы предложили - куки вообще перестали отправляться прежним кодом